# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/eswastha] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Tags: java, tomcat7, jndi

I shall describe the environment first

**environment:** : `Netbeans 7.2 and Tomcat 7.0.27.0 is configured with Netbeans ID`

when i take the build separately and put it in `webapps` folder and run than there is no issue but when i run the application in the IDE itself i get `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/eswastha] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].` this exception.

conf/context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/eswastha" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eswastha"
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               username="root" password="r14@17*" />
```

and web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jjdbc/eswastha</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

and the java class :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class JDBCManager {

    public Connection mysqlConnection()  {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        try {

            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/eswastha");
            dbConnection = ds.getConnection();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dbConnection;

    }
}
```

Please help me to identify the issue.

Regards

Comment: Hope this will help someone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484759/apache-tomcat-7-0-30-datasourcerealm-javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-name-j/23469293#23469293

Answer (score 1):

Is it missing? 
Check

```
 <res-ref-name>jjdbc/eswastha</res-ref-name>
 and
 <Resource name="jdbc/eswastha"..../>
```

---

Based on your comment :
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

---

Make sure your `JDBC Driver` and copy driver jar file under `tomcat-home/lib`.

It will be reference for your. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332276/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null-tomcat-sql-serv)

Comment: thanks, there was spelling mistake, but now i get this `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'` exception

Comment: i have included the needed lib also

Comment: Check it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292529/tomcat-with-mysql-cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-nul?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try to access the data source in full JNDI name, e.g.: "java:comp/env/jdbc/test"
Source: http://www.coderanch.com/t/442367/Tomcat/jdbc-bound-Context

On second note, I noticed that you've defined **jjdbc**, instead of **jdbc** in web.xml:

```
<res-ref-name>jjdbc/eswastha</res-ref-name>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Noted. Will remember and do that in all future posts.